Reading Bluetooth signals from a HIDS device using aioble and micropython on a Pi Pico
I have a Raspberry Pi Pico W that I want to have perform an action when a button is pressed on a bluetooth remote control I bought.
I can read the bluetooth remote and it's services and characteristics, but I have not figured out where button presses are communicated.
I have a bluetooth remote control that has the following characteristics:
Service: 12 30 UUID(0x180a)
  Characteristic: 18 16 2 UUID(0x2a24)
  Characteristic: 16 14 2 UUID(0x2a29)
  Characteristic: 24 22 2 UUID(0x2a26)
  Characteristic: 22 20 2 UUID(0x2a27)
  Characteristic: 20 18 2 UUID(0x2a25)
  Characteristic: 32 30 2 UUID(0x2a50)
  Characteristic: 30 28 2 UUID(0x2a2a)
  Characteristic: 28 26 2 UUID(0x2a23)
  Characteristic: 26 24 2 UUID(0x2a28)
Service: 8 11 UUID(0x1801)
  Characteristic: 11 10 32 UUID(0x2a05)
Service: 1 7 UUID(0x1800)
  Characteristic: 9 7 2 UUID(0x2a04)
  Characteristic: 7 5 2 UUID(0x2a01)
  Characteristic: 5 3 2 UUID(0x2a00)
Service: 74 79 UUID(0xae40)
  Characteristic: 78 76 4 UUID(0xae41)
  Characteristic: 79 78 16 UUID(0xae42)
Service: 35 73 UUID(0x1812)
  Characteristic: 41 39 26 UUID(0x2a4d)
  Characteristic: 39 37 6 UUID(0x2a4e)
  Characteristic: 52 50 26 UUID(0x2a4d)
  Characteristic: 48 47 14 UUID(0x2a4d)
  Characteristic: 45 43 26 UUID(0x2a4d)
  Characteristic: 64 62 26 UUID(0x2a4d)
  Characteristic: 60 58 26 UUID(0x2a4d)
  Characteristic: 56 54 26 UUID(0x2a4d)
  Characteristic: 75 73 4 UUID(0x2a4c)
  Characteristic: 73 71 2 UUID(0x2a4a)
  Characteristic: 69 68 26 UUID(0x2a33)
  Characteristic: 68 66 2 UUID(0x2a4b)
Service: 31 34 UUID(0x180f)
  Characteristic: 34 33 18 UUID(0x2a19)
Service: 128 133 UUID(0xae00)
  Characteristic: 132 130 4 UUID(0xae01)
  Characteristic: 133 132 16 UUID(0xae02)

This seems to be a HIDS device.
I'll also include my code that I used to get the above information. Forgive me it is quite hacky, but I don't know what is relevant and not so I'll provide it in it's entirety. It's part of a larger program, but the important part for the purposes of this is that try_to_connect is a function that gets run periodically
from util import singleton
from wifi import WLAN
from micropython import const

import bluetooth
import aioble
import asyncio


def log_info(*args):
    print("[aioble] I:", *args)


def ble_irq(event, data):
    log_info(event, data)
    aioble.core.ble_irq(event, data)


ble = bluetooth.BLE()
ble.irq(ble_irq)

SERVICE_UUID = bluetooth.UUID(0xAE40)
device_service = aioble.Service(SERVICE_UUID)
recv_characteristic = aioble.Characteristic(
    device_service,
    SERVICE_UUID,
    write=True,
    read=True,
    notify=True,
    capture=True,
)

_L2CAP_PSN = const(22)
_L2CAP_MTU = const(128)
l2cap_event = asyncio.Event()

recv_hids = aioble.Characteristic(
    aioble.Service(bluetooth.UUID(0x1812)),
    bluetooth.UUID(0x2A4D),
    write=True,
    read=True,
    notify=True,
)


@singleton
class Bluetooth:
    def __init__(self, scheduler):
        self.wifi = WLAN(scheduler)
        self.scheduler = scheduler
        scheduler.schedule("Bluetooth", 2000, self.try_to_connect)

    async def try_to_connect(self):
        try:
            print(f"Trying bluetooth")
            device = aioble.Device(aioble.ADDR_PUBLIC, "47:26:9c:1f:28:c1")
            connection = await device.connect(timeout_ms=2000)
            print(connection)
            if connection and connection.is_connected():
                print("Is connected")
                data = connection.read()
                print(data)
                services = []
                async for service in connection.services():
                    services.append(service)
                for s in services:
                    print(s)
                    async for c in s.characteristics():
                        recv_characteristic = aioble.Characteristic(
                            aioble.Service(bluetooth.UUID(s.uuid)),
                            bluetooth.UUID(c.uuid),
                            write=True,
                            read=True,
                            notify=True,
                            capture=True,
                        )
                        # data = recv_characteristic.read()
                        # if data:
                        print(f"  {c}")
                        # print(f"   {data}")

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Bluetooth Timeout")


The problem I have is that I can't seem to get a button press to send any information.
I'm not familiar enough with HIDS and bluetooth to really know what I need to be asking I'm afraid. I had hoped that tapping into ble.irq would print events when a button was pressed but it does not.
I also confirmed the remote control does work by connecting it to my phone. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?
